# Using "ToNumberField" as opposed to equations over the integers

Tags: regions, number-theory

Let `D>1` be a square-free rational integer, and write `\Q` for the rationals. I am trying to determine the (non-)membership of certain points of the form `{a+b√D,a-b√D}`, where `a,b \el \Q`, inside regions bounded by various hyperbolae of the form `Abs[(x - P)*(y - P')] < 1`, where `P = p+q√D` is some element of the ring of integers of the same real quadratic field `\Q(√D)`, and `P' = p-q√D` is its Galois conjugate.

Currently I do this using the function `RegionMember` applied to a `RegionIntersection` or `RegionUnion` of these regions, each of which is in turn defined by an `ImplicitRegion` delimited by the hyperbolic ranges. This works very well but is predictably quite slow.

My question is whether there is a better way of answering this type of question using `ToNumberField`. That is to say, is anything gained internally in these types of calculations by denominating the coordinates of the points first as members of a real quadratic field, rather than (I guess) treating them as rational multiples of high-precision reals?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Might be faster to evaluate `Abs[(x - P)*(y - P')] /. {x -> a + b \[Sqrt]D, y -> a - b \[Sqrt]D}`, either exactly or numerically, to see if it is less than 1.

Comment: Thank you, yes: that is a (much better-expressed) version of how I check the answers. But I didn't explain enough of the context, sorry -- in order to find the candidate points P, I need the regional intersections first.  It's a kind of bootstrap process.

Comment: It will be easier to consider this if you add a concrete example, with inputs and desired results. Right now I for one don’t know what it is that guides the bootstrapping.

Comment: Fair enough. I was avoiding that because it's about 30 lines of badly-written code on a bizarre little problem, and I was trying to restrict my question to whether the function ToNumberField adds anything per se to the integer-&real-based calcs, or whether they are really equivalent ways of wiring the same calculation once we look under the hood. I don't know enough to even begin to reverse-engineer that type of question in Mathematica. But as you say, for this specific issue perhaps it's better if I edit the question and add in an example.